# proportionally resize images according to screen width and align in 4 columns

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to build a grid of images on a company website to list their partners. As all those partners have icons with entirely different proportions that may not be modified in any way, this is a problem. The range of formats is about 1:2 to 5:1.

What I want is to place those into a grid with 3 columns that automatically resizes its width according to the browser width. The images inside it shall all have a maximum width (the column width minus a bit of margin) and a maximum height proportional to the current maximum width (e.g. format 2:1).

Inside the limits of maximum height and width, the image should proportionally scale as large as possible.

How can this be done, preferably using HTML and CSS only?

Extract from the current wordpress-generated code:

```
<div class="cr3_sponsorwrapper">
   <div class="fours-column">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <div class="cr3_sponsor_image">
            <img width="679" height="508" src="#" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="1" />
         </div>
      </a>
      <p></p>
   </div>
   <div class="fours-column">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <div class="cr3_sponsor_image">
            <img width="1000" height="634" src="#" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="2" />
         </div>
      </a>
      <p></p>
   </div>
   <!-- and so on... -->
</div>
```

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: Currently I wrap the `<img>`s in `<div>`s that have a `width: 22%` and `margin: 1%` and are laid out using `float: left`. But this results in the bad behaviour that multiple small icons may stack below each other when they are on the right of a large icon.

Comment: how are we supposed to supply an answer without seeing your code? please provide a MCVE! http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added an extract from the page. It was generated by wordpress.